# Is it possible to recruit more templar/skimishers/reapers?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

I've been playing for a few hours, and I've only gotten one of each.  Is it possible to get more?

Comment: I have not played enough of it yet, but I believe you can get a special mission to get another one. Those missions are rare though. I believe there was something about it in one of the streams prior to launch, but I can't quite remember what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get one extra faction soldier from the first resistance faction that you contact by using a covert action that requires high influence in that faction.

With the WotC tutorial on you always encounter the Reaper faction first making it only possible to get an extra Reaper.

I read this in another thread that said that a dev had said it during a livestream and it seemed correct my first full run of the game so I believe it to be true but if you find proof otherwise, please tell me.

Comment: Is that a more or less educated guess or taken from some reference?

Comment: I read it in a thread somewhere that a dev said this during a livestream and it was correct during my first full run in WotC and I had high influence with all factions quite a while and only got a 2nd reaper(first met faction). It also seems to be correct with your first run and the other answer in this thread so it was an educated guess I was almost certain of. Although I can not find a foolproof source now so I will change my answer to reflect that.

Comment: How does one start a campaign without meeting the Reaper first? I thought this was a story mission, not a tutorial option (as I avoided the actual tutorial with Jane Kelly, yet I still played the Outrider/Mox meeting mission)

Comment: When you start a new game you can choose if you wish to enable/disable "Lost and Abandoned" which is the Wotc tutorial/introduction.

Answer (score 6):

I was finally able to get another Reaper through a covert action.  As far as I've seen, that's the only way to get new faction-units.

Answer (score 4):

I'm almost finished with my first WotC run — which I really dragged out until November with a completely empty Avatar Project progress bar. I've got exactly *four faction soldiers*, the three initial ones from making contact and one additional Reaper from a covert op, I think it was simply called *"Recruit Soldier".* Since it was my first WotC run I did actually look out specifically at every turn for faction soldiers but alas, I got only the one extra.

I had two seemingly random faction missions, but those only allowed me to get more regular soldiers, so maybe that were just a new kind of regular new resistance mission types even though they were not introduced the same as the usual ones.

There might be an resistance order giving you Skirmishers. Unfortunately, I won't be able to figure out if these guys permanently join XCOM or just work in the mission for you as it is already deep in November and XCOM is really armed to the teeth already.

[image: Resistance Order Screenshot]

Comment: The "ADVENT units" that join you are just normal rookies.  They appear randomly on missions.

Comment: You can get a similar card from the Repears, and a rookie resistance member will randomly fight besides. you. That one is better as they will be using a plasma rifle if you researched it. They also aim better. The Skirmishers card is hardly worth it, only saving grace is that the defector has a grenade, while the resistance member does not.

Answer (score 1):

The expansion originally only allows you to recruit one additional faction soldier from the faction you first start with.

You can remedy it by use of this mod: [Recruit Multiple Heroes From All](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1126788564)

The author has a number of other "mods" that are actually fixes to the game, which I, personally, recommend. For example he also has a fix for the "Brutal" ability of the Hunter. The fix makes it so every attack reduces the **current** will of your soldiers, instead of the **maximum** as it is in the original expansion at this moment.

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug?  It sounds like it was intentional.

Comment: Yes, you are right this one doesn't look like bug. Since there are other bugs the author of that mod fixes I assumed this one was, too. I have no idea what they were thinking with that limit, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing the same game for quite awhile. I have everything researched and have done countless missions and have full influence with all the factions. All I have acquired is an extra reaper. So I truly believe it is only possible to get one extra soldier after the first three from other factions. If you find another way to recruit more please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

If one of your faction guys gets captured you get a mission to replace him if you save the captured one now you have two